# extjs4 on load listener not being invoked

Tags: extjs4

Pardon me if this doesnt make much sense as i am still trying to understand certain aspects of extjs.. I m trying to to dynamically fetch a menu when a page is loaded. But seems like my MenuFetch() function does not get called.

Here is my code and here is the page:
http://srikanthrajan.com/test/

```
    Center = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: "User Admin",
        region: 'center',
        layout: 'fit',
        dockedItems: {
            xtype: 'panel',
            dock: 'left',
            title: 'Main Menu',
            width: 160,
            layout: 'anchor',
            collapsible: true,
            collapseDirection: 'left',
            items: [
                {
                    defaults: {
                        width: 140,
                        layout: 'vbox',
                        xtype: 'linkbutton'
                    },
                    id: 'MainMenu',
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    listeners: {
                        load: function(menu) {
                            menu.show()
                            MenuFetch()
                            this.load()
                        }

                    }
                }
            ]
        }
});

//function that uses ajax to fetch menu items and add them
function MenuFetch() {
    Ext.getBody().mask('loading')
    var menu = Ext.ComponentManager.get('MainMenu')

    menu.removeAll(true)    
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'PanelScripts/getMenu.php',
        method: 'POST',

        callback: function(opt, success, response) {
            var text = response.responseText;
            var obj = Ext.JSON.decode(text);
            if (success && !obj.failure) {
                menu.add(obj)
                Ext.getBody().unmask()
                menu.show()
            } else {
                obj = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
                Ext.Msg.alert('Error',obj.Error)
                Ext.getBody().unmask()
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PS: I am not sure if I even need the load listener. Basically I need to call the menuftech function which fetches the menu items in a json format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Ext.ComponentLoader (or loader config property) to load remote content for the menu.  It seems like the xtype should be 'menu' instead of 'panel' based on what you are trying to accomplish.  Try something like this:

```
var adminPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'User Admin',
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'fit',
    dockedItems: {
        xtype: 'panel',
        dock: 'left',
        title: 'Main Menu',
        width: 160,
        layout: 'anchor',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items:[
              {
                 xtype: 'menu',
                 width: 100,
                 loader: {
                     url: 'foo.bar',
                     autoLoad: true,
                     callback: function(loader, success, response, options) {
                         var menu = adminPanel.down('menu');
                         if (success) {
                           menu.add(response.items);
                           menu.show();
                         }
                     },
                     scope: this
                 }
             }
         ]
     }
 });
```